# Reactor - retry based on item field value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm using a spring boot application with Webflux.

I need to retry the request if i get some error, but also, I need to check if an object property is true. This property is a boolean to check if i can retry.

Example:

```
webClient
        .post()
        .uri(object.getUrl())
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(docRequest))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Document.class)
        .retry()
        .filter(e -> object.isRetry())
```

i tried this way but the filter is not working.

There is any way to filter?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the more advanced features of retryWhen

Never done this before, but reading the [reference guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_retrying) this might work:

`.retryWhen(Retry.from(companion -> companion.filter(it -> object.isRetry())));`